# Candlesticks blurry when using plotly graph objects to plot them

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am plotting my candlestick with plotly graph objects, and they appear to be very unsharp, in comparison to using for example the tradingviews lightweight charting library. The problem is, that I want to have plotlys utility, but want to have sharp candles.

I think it has to do with the render mode, but I wasn't able to find any way to change the rendermode of plotly to canvas or webgl.

Comment: I agree with your points. There are two ways to make it clearer: line width and thinner whiskers. Here is the code to test it. `df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')[:50];
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],open=df['AAPL.Open'],high=df['AAPL.High'],low=df['AAPL.Low'],close=df['AAPL.Close'],line_width=1.0,whiskerwidth=0.5)]);
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white', height=600, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False);fig.show(render='svg')`